# Why CPU instruction Executed in RAM?

Tags: cpu

Why CPU executes Instructions in RAM and load programs into RAM before executing them instead of directly executing them on hard-disk.

Comment: Because you don't want to spend two weeks waiting for your spreadsheet to recalculate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading / writing data in memory is orders of magnitude faster than accessing data on a hard disk. This was especially true in the past when permanent storage devices were much slower (tape drives, etc.) so it made sense to load data into faster temporary storage.

Any data on a hard drive must be located (which requires the hardware to move the reading head, wait for the disk to be in the right position for a read, etc.) - this is a very time-comsuming process (compared to memory speeds). Memory addresses - with quite a bit of over-simplification - have constant (fast) access times; hard drive sectors don't.

Programs are not executing in memory - they're loaded into and stored in memory and the various instructions are read from there by the processor. Data used and generated by the program are also stored in memory (at least temporarily).

On mobile devices (tablets, cell phones, etc.) there may not be a hard drive (or equivalent secondary storage, like an external memory card) present so programs run from memory directly and store data there.

Comment: It means RAM is used because of its speed and random access capability.

Comment: @anshulgarg Yes - I updated the answer for that. Don't read this answer as tecnically accurate, though - I simplified it a lot to contain it in a short answer. For technical details on how RAM / HDD works, read various wikis and technical specs.

Comment: Isn't this completely incorrect? "On mobile devices (tablets, cell phones, etc.) there may not be a hard drive (or equivalent secondary storage, like an external memory card) present so programs run from memory directly and store data there."

Comment: @farukdgn Why do you think that excerpt is incorrect?

Comment: Oh sorry I thought you had written "programs run from storage"

Comment: "On mobile devices (tablets, cell phones, etc.) there may not be a hard drive (or equivalent secondary storage, like an external memory card) present so programs run from memory directly and store data there." - This IS incorrect. All devices always have secondary storage. Where else will they store all the user files and applications and the entire operating system image?

Comment: @TusharVazirani You're incorrect, not all devices have secondary storage. It's very convenient when they do (and when those follow file system semantics) but that's not always the case.

Comment: Can you give me a few examples? I would like to know.

Comment: @TusharVazirani PalmOS used to be like that.

Answer (score 0):

Instructions are neither executed in RAM nor on harddisk but solely in the CPU itself. Take a look a this article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_processing_unit#Operation